# Prerouting with iptables, destination port to DHCP ip

Tags: iptables, nat, dnat

I have an iptables rule that translates requests to the same IP from different internal hosts by changing the source port.

```
iptables -t NAT -A POSTROUTING -p TCP -d 173.32.1.2 --dport 873 \
-m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j SNAT --to-source 173.32.1.1:44000-44300
```

How do I handle responses from that host? How can I match the destination port of the reply packet to the IP of the internal host that's expecting it? This is what I have:

```
iptables -t NAT -A PREROUTING -p TCP -s 173.32.1.1 --sport 873 \
-m state --state ESTABLISHED -j DNAT --to-destination # what do I put here?
```

**An example of what I'm trying to achieve:**

Two hosts, `192.168.1.3` and `192.168.1.4`, both try to start a connection with `173.32.1.2`. The NAT changes the outgoing packets' source address and source port to respectively `173.32.1.1 : 44000` and `173.32.1.1 : 44001`.

The target `173.32.1.2` replies to both of them, with address and port destinations `173.32.1.1 : 44000` and `173.32.1.1 : 44001`. Now I want to forward these packets to the original senders, the first to `192.168.1.3` and the second to `192.168.1.4`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "handle responses from that host" ?

Comment: I'll edit the post with an example.

Comment: Is 173.32.1.1 a default router for 192.168.1.3 and .4? Why do you think that source port will be changed to 40000 and 40001?

Comment: @ALex_hha Yes it's the default router. For the example, I chose two ports at random from the range I specified. They need to be changed, so the destination can tell the two sending hosts apart.

Comment: There is no need in DNAT rule, SNAT will be enough. The default router (173.32.1.1) will find the original source ip (192.168.1.3 and 192.168.1.4) using connection tracking info, imho